# Why can't a conductive material be a piezoelectric material?

Tags: polarization, piezoelectric

I understand how a dielectric material, one that has no free electrons, can become piezoelectric (applying electric field that produces polarization of charge, etc.)

But why can't a conductive material, one that has free electrons become piezoelectric material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field inside a good conductor is always nearly zero due to the screening ability of free charges. A piezoelectric material requires an internal field to drive the crystal deformation. These requirements are in conflict.

It may be possible for a small piezoelectric effect to be present in the case of a weak conductor or within the typically-nm-deep screening layer at a metal surface. In each case, there could be a non-negligible electric field.

Comment: Thanks. But, why doesn't the electric field produced by the bound electrons in a dielectric cancel the external electric field?

Comment: Bound electrons are bound to a positive nucleus, so their polarizability is limited. They screen some, but not all of the electric field. Check out your favorite E&M text for details!

Comment: @Gilbert what is the 'screening layer at a metal surface'? ty:)